# Trouble using Qt with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, qt4

I am looking to do Qt development with Visual Studio 2005.

I have built the Qt libraries for Visual C++ and have downloaded the Qt plug-in using the steps outlined [here](http://dcsoft.com/community_server/blogs/dcsoft/archive/2009/03/06/how-to-setup-qt-4-5-visual-studio-integration.aspx).

I've set the `QTDIR` environment variable to point to the newly built Qt environment (`C:\Qt\vc`).

However, when I start Visual Studio, I get the following message:

```
  These Qt versions are inaccessible: 
  vc in c:\Qt\vc.
  Make sure that you have read access to all files in your Qt directories.
```

(And I definitely have read access)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330459/qt-5-1-1-with-visual-studio-2012-these-qt-version-are-inaccessible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it.  The key is to point `QTDIR` to the `qt` directory within the environment, so in my case `c:\Qt\vc\qt`. The error message is just not very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The similar error can arise in Visual Studio Add-In for Qt 5 when it fails to find proper directory itself (wrong QTDIR?)

The solution is to go to **QT5 — Qt Options** menu in Visual Studio and point it to the proper *c:\...\Qt5xx\qtbase* directory.

Note that you can completely delete QTDIR and Qt from PATH environment variable and switch Qt versions from within the **Qt Options** menu.

Answer (score 1):

After applying all your possible solutions I still had the same problem when building with Incredibuild.

I investigated the source code of the VS Addin and finally found a way to solve it:

In your Qt folder, you have to create a new dir `default` under the `mkspecs` folder, which contains a `qmake.conf` having the following content:

```
QMAKESPEC_ORIGINAL=../win32-msvc2012

include(../win32-msvc2012/qmake.conf)
```

*(Replace `win32-msvc2012` with the appropriate platform and buildtools)*

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the best answer:
It could also possible that your Qt installation is incomplete. This could happen if you install Qt by module-based third-party installers (like OSGeo4W). Qt Visual Studio Add-in detects `qmake.exe` to locate Qt installation. Therefore, if `qmake.exe` is absent, it will raise this error.
To resolve the problem, install the module which is named `qt5-devel` or so.