# Qt 5.1.1 with Visual Studio 2012 - These QT version are inaccessible

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I get this error when opening visual studio.

I installed from http://qt-project.org/downloads :

Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB) (Info)

and

Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.2 for Qt5

My Qt dir Path is:

C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1

[image: The error I got]

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443905/trouble-using-qt-with-visual-studio/26732539#26732539

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem in VS 2010 with Qt 5.5.
I did the followings and it is fixed.

1. In Visual Studio, go to `Qt5` > `Qt Options`
2. Click `Add`
3. In `Version Name:` type your version
4. In `Path:` select the path of the folder named msvcxxxx in your Qt directory(where xxxx is your VS version, in your case it must be something like `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012`)
5. If OK button is enabled than the path is correct, click it.

Alternatively, you can search your qt directory for `qmake.exe`. It must be in a folder named `bin`. Go up one level from it and copy that folder's path to the `Path:` textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the directory that contains the library files (it should contain a `bin` and a `include` directory).

Comment: Do you meen changing the QTDIR Environment variable toC:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\qtbase ? I tried to change to C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64 (this is the only dir under 5.1.1) and it didn't work - I get the same exact error.

Comment: What's under `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\ ` then ? You should specify (both for the QTDIR variable, and in the VS Add-In) the directory that contains, amongst other directories, the `.\bin` and `.\include` directories. I'd thought it'd be standard, but apparently it may differ amongst different installations (I compiled from source, that may vary...)

Comment: OK - so the path is: C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64 (has bin, include etc.), How do I add it to the VS Add-In?

Answer (score 0):

So I find the solution (at least patly - still have problems running on visual studio, but I solved the specific error.

So as JBL said VS is looking for the directory that has the  .\bin and .\include directories.

the problem was, that it the location is hard coded on the VS Add-In. So instead of **C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64**, it should be on **C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1** so

**I moved all the subfolders of C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64 to  C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1 .**

Next problem is, **Qt Creator still expects those files on  C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64**

So I copied them back (yes I have 2 copies of the SDK files).

This is not right, it should be expected on the same place, it should also be well defined how to install and use SDK both on Visual Studion and Qt Creator.

Hope that my issue would help you save some time.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019:
1) deleted record msvc2017_64
2) added msvc2017_64 setting path to D:\Qt\5.12.3\msvc2017_64 (whatever you have)
Error message disappeared.
[configuration with 2 toolsets at my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU1ES.png)