# Qt VS Tool is not loading properly the Qt Versions in VS 2019

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019

I hope someone can help me. The problem:

I have VS2019 with Qt VS Tool (2.7.2) and Qt Creator 5.0.2 based on 5.15.2 (via automatic Desktop installation of 6.2.0 incl. MSVC2019 ) installed. Both are working fine indepentendly. But if I try to set the Qt Versions in VS (under Extentions Qt VS Tools) the following message is shown

[image]

The output window on VS load shows these messages.

[image]

I double checked the access rights of C:\Qt and can't find any errors here, each existing user has read rights (I tried one version with C:\users\home\Qt no changes)
I tried already various complete new installations of both programs several times, but all failed.
Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: are you can compile a simple project with QtCreator ?

Comment: yes, with 2 compilers available - Qt Desktop Qt 6.2.0 MSVC2019 64bit-Debug and Qt Desktop Qt 6.2.0 MinGW 64bit, both are working

Comment: you can try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443905/trouble-using-qt-with-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks, I tried QTDIR already before, but without success.