# Loading Qt Versions property page error in Qt Vs Tools

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019

I meet the same problem as ["Qt VS Tool is not loading properly the Qt Versions in VS 2019"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69602235/qt-vs-tool-is-not-loading-properly-the-qt-versions-in-vs-2019).

- [sceenshot is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiys6.png)
- what I tried:

  1. Reinstall Visual Studio 2019.
  2. Reinstall Qt and Qt Vs Tools several times.
  3. Set QTDIR in my pc environment.

The problem is still present.
Could you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it now. The cause of the problem is that the previous Qt version information remains in registry. The solution steps are following:

1. Open regsitry editor. you can pressed keys **win+r**, then input `regedit`.
2. Find `计算机\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1609438195-1965026858-116498148-500\Software\Digia\Versions`.
3. Delete the contents of Versions folder.

[Reference screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58TRV.png)

**ps**:  The key `S-1-5-21-1609438195-1965026858-116498148-500` may be different in your pc.